# Comparing two list of lists to find common values Python

Tags: python, find, nested-lists

I have two lists of lists I want to iterate through them and compare the values in each bracket on the list bracket by bracket.....

```py
List_1
[[42, 43, 45, 48, 155, 157], [37, 330, 43, 47, 157], [258, 419, 39, 40, 330, 47], [419, 39, 44, 589, 599, 188].....
List_2
[[37, 330, 43, 47, 157], [258, 419, 39, 40, 330, 47], [419, 39, 44, 589, 599, 188], [41, 44, 526, 602, 379, 188]....
```

I need to compare the first bracket in `List_1 [42, 43, 45, 48, 155, 157]`
With the first bracket in `List_2 [37, 330, 43, 47, 157]`
the desired result is the numbers that are the same in each sequential bracket...for first bracket the result is 43 and 157

then I need to continue second bracket in List_1, with the second bracket in List_2 etc.

- Number of values in each bracket may vary
- I need each bracket in 1 list to compare with the corresponding bracket from the other list
- I don't need the results to be separate

I'm at a very basic level but, I've tried a few different things including using sets intersection, list matches. I'm sure that there is a simple way but only just getting started.

```py
    set_x = set([i[1] for i in list_1])
    print(set_x)
    set_y = set([i[0] for i in list_2])
    matches = set_x.intersection(set_y)
    print(matches)
```

this is providing an answer that is way off `{3, 8, 396, 12,}` and I can't really work out what it's doing.

also tried this

```py
    common_elements=[]
    import itertools 
    for i in list(itertools.product(coords_list_1,coords_list_2)):
        if i[0] == i[1]:
            common_elements.append(i[0])
            print(common_elements)
```

but it produces a mass of results.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Use `zip` and set's `intersection`:

```
for x, y in zip(List_1, List_2):
    print(set(x).intersection(y))

# {43, 157}
# {330, 47}
# {419, 39}
# {188, 44}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your approach tackles the elements in the wrong "axis". For instance:

```
set_x = set([i[1] for i in list_1])
```

creates a set of the 2nd element of each list.

In those cases, you have to forget about the indexes.

you just want to `zip` sublists together to perform intersection between them

```
List_1 = [[42, 43, 45, 48, 155, 157], [37, 330, 43, 47, 157], [258, 419, 39, 40, 330, 47], [419, 39, 44, 589, 599, 188]]
List_2 = [[37, 330, 43, 47, 157], [258, 419, 39, 40, 330, 47], [419, 39, 44, 589, 599, 188], [41, 44, 526, 602, 379, 188]]

result = [set(x) & set(y) for x,y in zip(List_1,List_2)]
```

result:

```
>>> result
[{43, 157}, {330, 47}, {419, 39}, {188, 44}]
```